# XSLT-1.0 to read a specific substring from a message

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've below message in a variable .

```
7c&#13; {"code":3001,"message":"issued"}&#13; 0&#13; &#13;
```

I would like to take the message starting with '{' and ending with '}' using XSLT. I tried using `sub-string()` and `starts-with` functions, but without success.

My final out put should be

> {"code":3001,"message":"issued"}

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0 , I tried substring-after and before which give me text after '{' and before '}' , also I see jsonresponse[starts-with(.,'{')] but not sure how to get the text ends with '}'.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: it was answered and have updated my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you could use `analyze-string` with `matching-substring` inside, to process the captured *regex*.

Let's move to an example. Start with a source XML given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
  <message>7c {"code":3001,"message":"issued"} 0</message>
</main>
```

Then we can use such XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\{{(.*)\}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note the content of `regex` attribute.

- In XSLT curly braces must be doubled in order to tell them apart from
  an *attribute value template*.
- But these curly braces are here **literal** curly braces, i.e. we are looking
  just for `{` and `}` chars (they are not here as delimiters of repetition
  counts for the preceding regex). For this reason we have to precede
  each of them with a backslash.
- Between these curly braces we have a capturing group `(...)`.
- We refer to the content of the captured group in `regex-group(1)` below.

If you need, you can put more capturing groups in the regex, to capture
individual parts of the message and then make some use of them.

But if you are really limited to XSLT 1.0 you can:

- Start from `substring-before` to cut off `}` and everything after.
- Then use `substring-after` to cut off `{` and everything before.

Or maybe you need the text **with** surrounding curly braces?
Then use `concat` to prepend `{` and append `}`.

Comment: Thank you all ,  Appreciate your help !!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried substring-after and before which give me text after '{' and
>   before '}'

If you're using XSLT 1.0, then do exactly that, and add the missing separators as text - for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">7c {"code":3001,"message":"issued"} 0 </xsl:variable>

<xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($var, '{'), '}')"/>
<xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
```

returns:

```
{"code":3001,"message":"issued"}
```

---

In XSLT 2.0, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($var, '.*(\{.*\}).*', '$1')"/>
```

to get the same result.